# Pressing "enter" in ExtJS-generated search box not working in IE

Tags: extjs, input, triggers

I inherited some code and I'm trying to isolate a bug that we found in IE only. ExtJS is used to generate a searchbox. Ext creates an `<img>` that acts as the trigger for searching.

In IE, you can click on the img to submit the search. However, if you press enter it activites an onClick button that appears farther down the page. Code below. How can I make sure the 'specialkey' is assigned to trigger the search? (I'm a little unclear why it works ok in non-IE browsers).

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
// create user extensions namespace (Ext.ux.form)
Ext.namespace('Ext.ux.form');

//  Ext.ux.form.SearchableTextField constructor
Ext.ux.form.SearchableTextField = function(config) {
    // call parent constructor
    Ext.ux.form.SearchableTextField.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
    // associate ENTER key with button click
    this.on('specialkey', function(f, e) {
        if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
            this.onTriggerClick();
        }
    }, this);
} // end of Ext.ux.form.SearchableTextField constructor

// extend
Ext.extend(Ext.ux.form.SearchableTextField, Ext.form.TriggerField, {
    triggerClass: 'x-form-search-trigger',
    onTriggerClick : function() {
        alert('customize in you app code');
    }
}); // end of extend
var tb = new Ext.Toolbar({
    renderTo: 'searchbox'
});

var search = new Ext.ux.form.SearchableTextField({
    triggerClass:'x-form-search-trigger banner-searchbox-submit',
    id:'banner-searchbox',
    width:100,
    onTriggerClick: function(){
        var x = this.getRawValue();
        this.setRawValue('');
        document.forms[0].method = 'post';
        document.forms[0].action = 'find.php?site=<?=$site?>&lang=<?=$lang?>';
        document.forms[0].qrystring.value = x;
        var pN = document.getElementById("pageNum");
        if (pN != null) {  
            document.forms[0].pageNum.value = 1;
        }
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
});
var searchPat = tb.add('-','<?=$menuPatients[$lang][2]?>: ', ' ', search);
tb.doLayout();
```

Comment: It turned out that we fixed this not by changing the extjs, but by switching the buttons that appeared farther down the DOM (and were getting triggered in IE). Instead of <input type="button"> switched to using <button> and this solved our problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possibly a scope issue, try changing your definition of `Ext.ux.form.SearchableTextField` to this

```
Ext.ux.form.SearchableTextField = function(config) {
  var me = this;
  // call parent constructor
  Ext.ux.form.SearchableTextField.superclass.constructor.call(me, config);
  // associate ENTER key with button click
  me.on('specialkey', function(f, e) {
    if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
        me.onTriggerClick();
    }
  }, me);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Didn't fix the problem, but now that I look further, it definitely appears to be some sort of scope problem. Is there some way to specify where the onTriggerClick() should go?

Comment: as a quick hack you can use `Ext.getCmp('idOfComponent').onTriggerClick();`

Comment: Although this didn't fix our problem, it definitely proved useful. See my note on my original question regarding what we changed.